# Ambient module declaration cannot specify relative module name

Tags: angularjs, module, typescript, angular, definitelytyped

I am using the Angular 2.My project is working but the following errors are displayed in Visual Studio :

[image]

typings.json :

```
{
       "ambientDependencies": {
        "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"
    }
}
```

package.json :

```
{
    "name": "asp-net-angular2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "TestStack",
    "description": "",
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "typings install"
    },
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",

        "systemjs": "0.19.27",
        "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
        "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

        "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.7",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
        "jquery": "^2.2.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^1.8.10",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
        "fs": "^0.0.2",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
        "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.1",
        "gulp-tsc": "^1.1.5",
        "del": "^2.2.0",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
        "gulp-cssnano": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-html-replace": "^1.5.4",
        "gulp-htmlmin": "^1.0.5",
        "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
        "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
        "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.16",

        "typings": "^0.8.1"
    },
    "repository": { }
}
```

tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

and project setting :

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>True</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>True</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
  </PropertyGroup>
```

How do I eliminate these errors.I tried but did not succeed. my error on `.d.ts` file :

Ambient module declaration cannot specify relative module name

Comment: one thing what I could suggest you is `ES5` should be changed to `ES6`, but still I want to know how you got this working?

Comment: you cannot use a relative path when declaring a module, it has to be an absolute path, in your case declare module ../../Observable is invalid and not allowed by typescript

Answer (score 0):

i see you have tsconfig.json, so you might be using command line to build your tsc files.

You may block compilation in Visual studio by including below in your project settings (and all errors will go away as you are not building inside VS),

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

else you may Include ts files and main.d.ts explicitly by adding these into project settings.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <TypeScriptCompile Include="$(ProjectDir)\src\**\*.ts" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <TypeScriptCompile Include="$(ProjectDir)\src\main.d.ts" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: this doesn't helped me, do you have another alternative?